# Tracking an email

Tags: asp.net, email

I am developing a  bulk mail management project in ASP.NET. I want to track who opened my mails. I know that this can be done by embedding a small transparent image in my mail. So whenever the receiver opens the mail the image is automatically downloaded from my server. But I have no idea that how can I get to know that image is getting downloaded from my server and which mail id is downloading it. Please help me as early as possible.

Comment: Look for handlers, write a handler for supplying the image instead, and let the handler accept the email address for input. So you image source would be something like Handler?email=EmailIdOfPerson. If this helps please mark the comment as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Send email as html
Include somthing like
http://www.myserver.com/counter.aspx?userid=xxxxx'>

You may need to add some additional parameter to url, like email id to make sure you log only once, not every time user open an email

Inside counter.aspx run the code to log user and then output some image in the response.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. This will be much helpful.

Comment: My count code will be executed only if receiver clicks on the link. I don't want link tracking. I want open tracking. Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got another way out to get open statistics in following link:
http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/default.aspx

Comment: Here one more problem occurred. I am not able to get open stats if it is gmail account. How to do it? Please help